# Gtk.StackSwitcher, childs with icons expand

Tags: gtk, stack, vala

I'm working with the `Gtk.StackSwitcher`, adding childs with an "icon-name" property to display the icon in the StackSwitcher.

Now I want the childs to expand, to use the whole space which is available in the `StackSwitcher`. Is there any solution how i can do this?

Comment: Can you show snippet or some code how you did that? How you show icons in Gtk.StackSwitcher?

Answer (score 0):

To get a Gtk3 widget to expand you can set the `expand` property to `True`. There are also `hexpand` and `vexpand` properties if you only want to expand in one direction. What the widget does with the extra space is determined by the `halign` and `valign` properties, the default is to expand to use all the allocated space.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I really don't know where to set the property. The StackSwitcher seems to use all the available space, but the switcher Buttons have a light padding around the picture even if there is many space left.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question the first time. Is the extra space you want to use inside or outside the buttons?

Comment: NP. I want the StackSwitcherButtons to use the whole space of the StackSwitcher.

Comment: I'm not sure there's an easy way to do that, you could iterate over the buttons using gtk_container_foreach() but I'm not sure that's really good practice as you're messing with the internals of a widget. Normally there isn't much space between stack and the switcher so it's clear that one controls the other, is there a reason you have so much space around the StackSwitcher?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the "homogeneous" property to true on the StackSwitcher will achieve the effect you desire.